# filter collection in form builder [symfony2]

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, twig, query-builder

I have a table named Images that contains a list of logos. I would like to retrieve only logos of airlines companies.

I have this error:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match
>   number of tokens")

```
->add('logo', 'genemu_jqueryselect2_entity', array(
    'class' => 'FLYBookingsBundle:Images',
    'property' => 'alt',
    'placeholder' => 'Choose your company',
    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->where('u.transport_mode = :AIRPLANE')
            ->groupBy('u.id')
            ->orderBy('u.alt', 'ASC');
    },))
```

---

```
+---+----------------------------+-------------+-----------------+
|id |     path                   |      alt    |tranport_mode    |
+---+----------------------------+-------------+-----------------+
| 1 | /symfony/web/etihad.jpg    | etihad      |AIRPLANE         |
| 2 | /symfony/web/singapore.jpg | singapore   |AIRPLANE         |
| 3 | /symfony/web/InterCape.jpg | InterCape   |BUS              |
+---+----------------------------+-------------+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to bind parameter using `setParameter()` function

```
setParameter("mode", "AIRPLANE")
```

**Code**

```
->add('logo', 'genemu_jqueryselect2_entity', array(
    'class' => 'FLYBookingsBundle:Images',
    'property' => 'alt',
    'placeholder' => 'Choose your company',
    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->where('u.transport_mode = :mode')
            ->setParameter("mode", "AIRPLANE")
            ->groupBy('u.id')
            ->orderBy('u.alt', 'ASC');
    },))
```

You've declared a binding called `:mode` but you never actually bind anything to it.

[Read more about binding parameters in doctrine](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#values-clause)